# indicator-sound missing + other sound problems 13.10

Tags: 13.10, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I seem to have "destroyed" my sound in Ubuntu 13.10...

I can change my sound through `alsamixer` and `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` works fine. However the indicator-sound is missing (but installed, and purging and reinstallation does not help). Moreover I cannot open `gnome-control-center sound` via terminal because it says :

`Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/control-center-1/panels/libsoundnua.so`

reinstallation of pulseaudio, libpulse0 dies not help...

EDIT: I forgot to mention something: The terminal also says: `libpulsecommon-4.99.so: Cannot open the shared-object file: File or directory not found` (or something similar, it's originally in german) so in which package is this libpulsecommon file? All I have on my computer is a `libpulsecommon-4.0.so` file, so probably that's the problem

Comment: Does `sudo apt-file search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/control-center-1/panels/libsoundnua.so` return anything? You may have to install `apt-file` first, and run `sudo apt-file update`. It will try and find what package the file is supposed to be from. Also try `sudo apt-get -f install` - check in case it tries to remove anything, but it should just sort out dependencies.

Comment: the weird thing is, that the file exists on my computer in this exact location ... it's in the gnome-control-center package

Comment: I would of thought it would of been, `control-center-1` is a give away, but just checking. Have you tried moving the file elsewhere? It could be having problems actually reading the file.

Comment: I updated my question, there seems to be a problem with another file on my computer. Btw: moving the `libsoundnua.so` doesn't change anything

Comment: How do you think you 'destroyed' it? Was it after an update or something?

Comment: Well, I think one thing I did was to upgrade wine, but purging of wine doesn't help either...

Comment: this package seems to be corrupted as well: `libpulse-mainloop-glib0` I can't reinstall it. Damn, I don't want to reinstall my whole ubuntu